# Movement seem choppy but FPS is good

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I just finished writing my movement script and my game seems like it has a low framerate. I booted up fraps and found that my game is running at 60FPS. What could be the issue? Also this is a top down RPG style game by the way.
Here's my movement script if that helps:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
Vector2 _playerPosition;
public GameObject Player;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    _playerPosition = Vector2.zero;
}

// Update is called once per frame
public float speed = 3f;
void Update()
{
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
{
   transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If this is script is attached inside the player object inspector you really don't need the GameObject line. The Time.deltaTime is time to complete last frame. You have issues with timing you want to use _Time[0] which is time since program has started and say everytime it has increased allow movement. 0 inside the bracket is 1/20 of a second, use 1 for 1 second and then there is 2 and 3 for use in the bracket.

Comment: @Edward How would I add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching YouTube tutorials can be real helpful in learning new things about Unity. look here at [4 min](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXQI_0ILEW4) and you will see code that I would try for your transform like this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
    transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f); //x,y,z
}
```

The suggestion I had in the question's comment, I would put your if statements inside a method outside the update and call the method say every second like so, which Unity has a good community of [question/answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/874092/every-001th-second-move-game-object.html) as well

```
InvokeRepeating("MyMethod", 1f, 1f); //I believe this is every second
```

I would also make a suggest change to your code that would reduce the lines and allow for movement keys of left,right,up,down as well as A,D,W,S and us of joystick movements.

```
void Update(){
    transform.Translate(speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 
                      speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime)
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking... What would smoothDeltaTime help?

Comment: not really sure, seems like it would be comparable of DC to AC. What I had just read implies that DeltaTime is to help with translating your speed according to the FPS, so if your FPS is slow it creates a larger move than if your FPS was fast.

Comment: @LiamEarle look at the update as well for shorter code suggestion

Comment: Yeah. That's kinda what my code looks like. I'm new to C# and unity but I've done a lot of work in GML for gamemaker and I've done some Minecraft modding in java.

Comment: @LiamEarle Did this work for your smoother movement?

Comment: yeah. I guess it'll also look a bit smoother when I finish my animation's for the sprite.

Comment: selecting answer helps the community, plus upvote on the answer. Also upvote "only" comments that add value to your understanding

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot. I'll do that now.

Comment: @LiamEarle Just an FYI its always good to search for question/answers that you may have so as not to post duplicates, then if you find such upvote the question as well